# Play audio (MP3) files from folder in gridview with filepath in database but the audio file will be outside to the website directory

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I wanna play song from database but only path of song is stord in database so how to do this and i don't wanna use id of song i wanna select song by column name (ASP.NET)(SQL server) but here audio will be outside of the website directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get access to a file that is not publicly available. You must find a way to make your song accessible from www. The easiest way is to move your file into the website directory.

Comment: i don't want to move it website directory.Is there any way?If there please help me

Comment: Then you will have to create an asp file that will read your file locally an deliver its content to the web.

Comment: Is there any example available in google so that i can understand

Comment: You have to search by yourself.
Maybe this will help you : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306654/how-to-write-binary-files-to-the-browser-using-asp.net-and-visual-c-.net

Comment: Thanks For your help

Comment: how to integrate a windows media player in asp.net